# Edit and save element to XML file using Linq

Tags: c#, xml, wpf, linq, listbox

I'm trying to make a small XML editor. It loads an XML file, displays all book titles (in my example file) in a listbox. Clicking on a title displays all information about the book in a textbox. If the information should be modified, the user can click on an Edit button, and the information can now be edited in a new textbox. Finally, the changes are saved and both textboxes cleared - and, if possible, the titles from the newly updated XML file should be reloaded into the listbox ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/11rSr.png)).

The listbox and first textbox operations work fine, thanks to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40569520/how-to-display-xml-in-a-listbox-and-pass-it-to-a-textbox-in-c#new-answer).
The problem arises when I try to send the XML values to the second textbox. Either changes aren't saved or, if they are, the rest of the XML file disappears.

I suppose that a solution might consist in adding the information (and its changes) to a new XML element and then deleting the old one, but so far, and I've been trying for a while now, I simply can't figure out how to do it. It's for the same reason, and I know it's bad style, my code stops short where the problem begins. I'd be glad if someone could help me out.

My example XML:

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<!-- This file represents a fragment of a book store inventory database -->
<books>
  <book genre="autobiography">
    <title>The Autobiography of Benjamin Franklin</title>
    <author>Franklin, Benjamin</author>
    <year>1981</year>
    <price>8.99</price>
  </book>
  <book genre="novel">
    <title>The Confidence Man</title>
    <author>Melville, Herman</author>
    <year>1967</year>
    <price>11.99</price>
  </book>
  <book genre="philosophy">
    <title>The Gorgias</title>
    <author>Plato</author>
    <year>1991</year>
    <price>9.99</price>
  </book>
</books>
```

And my .cs

```
    private void btnLoadXML_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var xmlDoc = XDocument.Load("books03.xml");

        var elements = from ele in xmlDoc.Elements("books").Elements("book")
                       where ele != null
                       select ele;

        bookList = elements.ToList();

        foreach (var book in bookList)
        {
            string title = book.Element("title").Value;
            listBox1.Items.Add(title);
        }
    }

    private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var book = bookList[listBox1.SelectedIndex];

        textBox1.Text = 
            "Title: " + book.Element("title").Value + Environment.NewLine +
            "Author: " + book.Element("author").Value + Environment.NewLine +
            "Year: " + book.Element("year").Value + Environment.NewLine +
            "Price: " + book.Element("price").Value;
    }

    private void btnEdit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox2.Visible = true;
        btnSaveClose.Visible = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try xml linq :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);
            string searchName = "The Autobiography of Benjamin Franklin";
            XElement book = doc.Descendants("book").Where(x => (string)x.Element("title") == searchName).FirstOrDefault();

            XElement price = book.Element("price");

            price.SetValue("10.00");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: But how do I implement it in my code? Adding it under 'btn_edit()' in some way?